# font color on css and tables

Tags: html, css

I am making a newsletter template in foundation. The following table consist of 2 `<th>` that have the content "Reservationnumber" and "23425-FF3234". I have around 60 of these `<th>`. I would like to give the font a color. I can make that work if I set the class `class="reservation__fontcolor"` on each `<strong>` tag and `<th>` tag. But when I set it on the table that surrounds the `<th>` tag, it is not working.

Is there a way where I can set the `class="reservation__fontcolor"` on a more global level, so I do not have to copy/paste the class tag 60 times?

In the following code I tried to set the `<th class="small-6 large-6 columns first reservation__fontcolor">` on the `<th>` tag that have both include the `<td>` tag. But that is not working. Why?

**CSS**

```
.reservation__fontcolor {
        color: red;
       }
```

**HTML**

```
<table align="center" class="wrapper header float-center bgcolor">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="wrapper-inner">
        <table align="center" class="container" style="background-color:transparent">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- Reservationnumber -->
                <table class="row collapse">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="small-6 large-6 columns first reservation__fontcolor">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                <strong>Reservationnumber:</strong>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </th>
                      <th class="small-6 large-6 columns last">
                        <table>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th>
                                23425-FF3234
                              </th>
                              <th class="expander"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>                             
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code cannot be shorter than this. It is relevant to see that there is 3 tables inside another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add class reservation__fontcolor to your table and then add this on your css:

```
.reservation__fontcolor tr th{
    color: red;
}
```

It's like a path, you can read it as follows: all the th tags, inside tr tags, inside an element of class reservation__fontcolor get the properties defined.

This prevents any other th tags outside a table from that class from getting the property, which would happen for example with:

```
th{
    color: red;
}
```

If you wanted both th and td tags to get the same properties but only when inside a class table, you could do:

```
.reservation__fontcolor tr th, .reservation__fontcolor tr td{
    color: red;
}
```

I think the difference between those concepts is the key to understand how it works and applying it on different situations.

Good luck.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one single table and you can ca color by  tag. I have created a`enter code here`[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/rs3kwvuv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work with [Nested CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).

In the example below I am working with a minimal scope just to figure the idea, however, it can start in the first `table` to reach the `th` wanted.

CSS:

```
<style>
    table.reservation__fontcolor th{
        color red;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="row collapse reservation__fontcolor">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="small-6 large-6 columns first ">
            <table class="reservation__fontcolor">
                <tbody class="">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <strong>Reservationnumber:</strong>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th class="small-6 large-6 columns last">
            <table>
                <tbody class="reservation__fontcolor">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            23425-FF3234
                        </th>
                        <th class="expander"></th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```